Euler spiral derivatives
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by
$$f(t) = \exp(I t^2/2),$$
where $I$ is the imaginary unit. Then $f$ is the first derivative of the Euler spiral.
Problem
Provide a non-recursive formula for the n:th derivative $f^{(n)}(t)$ where $n \in 
\mathbb{N}$.
Instances
Sagemath will happily compute an arbitrary derivative. Here are some of the first, where I have divided away the common factor $f(t)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{(1)}(t) / f(t) & = I*t \\
f^{(2)}(t) / f(t) & = -t^2 + I \\
f^{(3)}(t) / f(t) & = -I*t^3 - 3*t \\
f^{(4)}(t) / f(t) & = t^4 - 6*I*t^2 - 3 \\
f^{(5)}(t) / f(t) & = I*t^5 + 10*t^3 - 15*I*t \\
f^{(6)}(t) / f(t) & = -t^6 + 15*I*t^4 + 45*t^2 - 15*I \\
f^{(7)}(t) / f(t) & = -I*t^7 - 21*t^5 + 105*I*t^3 + 105*t \\
f^{(8)}(t) / f(t) & = t^8 - 28*I*t^6 - 210*t^4 + 420*I*t^2 + 105 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
These were computed with the following Sagemath script:
t, k = var('t', 'k')
df = exp(I * (1/2) * t^2)
with assuming(t, 'real'):
    print('\\begin{aligned}')
    for n in range(1, 9):
        print(f'f^{{({n})}}(t) / f(t) & = {(diff(df, t, n) / df).simplify_full()} \\\\')
    print('\\end{aligned}')


Have a look at https://oeis.org/A100861

Nice. So the absolute value of the k:th coefficient of $f^{(n)}(t) / f(t)$ is $T(n, k) = n!/(k! (n - 2k)! 2^k)$. Hmm. I guess one could guess a formula from here.

What seems to hold is $d^n \exp(t^2/2) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} T(n, k) t^{n - 2k}$.

With trial and error I got $d^n \exp(I t^2 / 2) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} T(n, k) I^{n - k} t^{n - 2k}$, and Sagemath agrees for $n \leq 8$. Proof is missing.

You can also check out Faa di Bruno's formula in case you want to consider variants of this problem.

The derivatives of $g(z) = \exp(-x^2/2)$ can be expressed with the help of the probabilist's Hermite polynomials:
$$
 g^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^n \operatorname{He}_n(x) g(x) \, ,
$$
see also Higher derivatives of an exponential function. The Hermite polynomials have the explicit expression
$$
\operatorname{He}_n(x) = 
n! \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(-1)^{m}}{m!(n-2m)!} \frac {x^{n-2m}}{2^{m}} \,. 
$$
Then $f(t) = \exp(i t^2/2) = g(\omega t)$ where $\omega$ is chosen such that $\omega^2 = -i$. It follows that
$$
 f^{(n)}(t) = \omega^n (-1)^n \operatorname{He}_n( \omega t) g(\omega t) = P_n(t) f(t) 
$$
with $P_n(t) = \omega^n (-1)^{n} \operatorname{He}_n( \omega t)$. Using $\omega^2 = -i$ this simplifies to
$$
 P_n(t) =  \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{n! i^{n-m}}{2^m m!(n-2m)!} t^{n-2m} \,. 
$$
The (absolute values of the) coefficients of the Hermite polynomials are also known as Bessel numbers, compare A100861 in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®.
Check the result with Maxima:
(%i1) P(n, t) := sum(n! * (%i)^(n-m)/(m! * (n-2*m)!) * t^(n-2*m)/2^m, m , 0, floor(n/2))$

(%i2) P(1, t);
(%o2)                                %i t

(%i3) P(2, t);
                                          2
(%o3)                               %i - t

(%i4) P(3, t);
                                       3
(%o4)                            - %i t  - 3 t

(%i5) P(4, t);
                                4         2
(%o5)                          t  - 6 %i t  - 3

(%i6) P(8, t);
                    8          6        4           2
(%o6)              t  - 28 %i t  - 210 t  + 420 %i t  + 105


Let the OP's polynomials be $\operatorname{Hi}_n(t)=\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{f(t)}$, $n\geq0$. By Cauchy's integral formula it can be shown that
$$e^{i(\frac{z^2}2+tz)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{Hi}_n(t)\frac{z^n}{n!}\tag1$$
is their generating function. On the other hand,
$$e^{2tz-z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_{n}(t)\frac{z^n}{n!}\tag2$$
is the generating function for the physicist's Hermite polynomials.
From $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$\operatorname{Hi}_n(t)=\frac{w^{3n}}{(\sqrt2)^n}H_n\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt2\,w}\right)$$
where $w=\exp(\tfrac{\pi i}4)$.

The subscript of $\textrm{Hi}$ is missing in equation (1).

@kaba Thanks for the notice.
